# is there any working/reliable open source TCP/IP Server App in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

is there any working/reliable open source TCP/IP Server App in C#?

Comment: uhm, probably. What kind of server? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Given TCP/IP is so low level, it will be impossible to adequately answer your question without further info.  Voting to close.  In the interim, you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533/reading-from-a-socket-in-c and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx.  Might help.

Comment: a client PC connect to this server, and send a string message every time, very similar to chat server , but my app is not a chat application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have very specific requirements, but there is a whole bunch at [Codeplex(search:server+socket)](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=server%20socket&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=3), just pick one that suits your need there.